# number of quadratic residues in finite field

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Is there a way to determine how many quadratic residues are there in the finite field $F_q$ for $q = p^k$?

It seems if $q=p$ exactly $(p-1)/2$ are residues and the same amount are not. Does analogy holds for $q = p^k$?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Just mimic the proof of $(p-1)/2$ in the $F_p$ case.  If $p\ne 2$, then any non-zero element $x$ of $F_q$ still satisfies $x \ne -x$.  Alternatively, use the mildly deeper fact that $F_q^\times$ is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, if $p$ is odd then exactly one half of the non-zero elements are squares. If $q$ is even, then squaring is an automorphism of $\Bbb{F}_q$, so everything is a square.

Answer (score 3):

$s:k^{\times}\to k^{\times}, s(a)=a^2$ is a (multiplicative) group homomorphism.  In characteristic $\neq 2$, the kernel of $s$ has order two and if $k$ is finite, the set of quadratic residues, $s(k^{\times})$, has size $|k^{\times}/\{\pm1\}|=(q-1)/2$.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comment saying 'mimic the proof of $(p-1)/2$', here is that proof, taken from [this document](http://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/extremal07/recitation2.pdf) from ETH Zurich.

The theorem is:

> Let $q$ be an odd prime power, and $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$,
> then:
>
> - $a \in QR(q), \iff a^{(q-1)/2} = 1$
> - $a \in QNR(q), \iff a^{(q-1)/2} = -1$
> - $| QNR(q) | = \frac{q-1}{2} = | QR(q) |$

And the essence of the proof is:

> 1:  A polynomial of degree $d$, with coefficients from a field $R$, can
> have at most $d$ roots in $R$.
> 2: Lagrange's Theorem: In a finite group $G$, $x^{|G|} = 1$ for any $x \in G$.
>
> On the one hand, by Fact 1, the polynomial $x^{q-1} -1 = 0$ cannot have more than $q - 1$ roots by Legrange's theorem, because all the elements in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ are roots.
>
> Consequently, since $x^{q-1} - 1 = ( x^{(q-1)/2} + 1 ) ( x^{(q - 1)/2} - 1 )$ and the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$ has no (non-trivial) zero divisors, again Fact 1 implies that both factors $( x^{(q-1)/2} + 1 )$ and $( x^{(q-1)/2} - 1 )$ must have exactly $\frac{q-1}{2}$ roots.