# Definition of quadratic residues in $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q = p^n$.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

For $\mathbb{F}_p$, I know that the definiton of quadratic residue (and non-residue)  is :

$a $ is a quadratic residue if $gcd(a,p) =1$ (i.e $a \neq 0 $ in $\mathbb{F}_p$) and $x^2 \equiv a $ $mod(p)$ has a solution.

$a $ is a quadratic non-residue if  $gcd(a,p) =1$ (i.e $a \neq 0 $ in $\mathbb{F}_p$) and $x^2 \equiv a $ $mod(p)$ has no solution.

Now what are the definition in case of $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=p^n$? Is the condition $gcd(a,q) =1$  there in the definition?

Also in case of $\mathbb{F}_p$ we get $(p-1)/2 $ residues and $(p-1)/2 $ non-residues. Is there a similar result in case of $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: Does this answer your second question? [number of quadratic residues in finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939151/number-of-quadratic-residues-in-finite-field)  The first Answer there also answers your first question.

Comment: Elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$ aren't integers. Quadratic residue is $a\ne 0$ and $a= b^2$ for some $b\in \Bbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Yes, the number of non-zero squares in $\Bbb{F}_q$, $q$ odd, is exactly $(q-1)/2$. When $q$ is even, all the elements of the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ are squares. But, it is a bit unnatural to call them quadratic residues when $q$ is not a prime.

Comment: But, what reuns said. I'm afraid some parts of the question raise the suspicion that you don't know what the finite fields look like. For example, one way of looking at the field $\Bbb{F}_9$ is to list the elements in the form $a+bi$ with $i^2=-1=2$ and $a,b$ residue classes of integers modulo $3$. So in $\Bbb{F}_9$, the non-zero square are $1$, $2=-1=i^2$, $(1+i)^2=2i$ and $(1-i)^2=-2i=i$.